# how to pass function in json as a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

in arrayRec , onShow value should be a function.

Following is my reference code.

Any **help?**

**This is my reference code:**

```
if (rec.element_flag == '111'){ 
        var arrayRec = [];
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url: "/aps/one-url",                
            success: function(responseData){
                for (var i = 0; i < responseData.length; i++){
                    var recJ;
                    var newFunction1 = function onshowdata(counter){                    
                        if(responseData[counter].fields.on_show_fn != null){
                            return function responseData[counter].fields.on_show_fn;
                        }               
                        else
                        return;
                    }
                    recJ = {
                        element: responseData[i].fields.element_class,                  
                        placement: responseData[i].fields.placement,
                        title: responseData[i].fields.title,
                        content: responseData[i].fields.content,
                        onShow: newFunction1(i)                 
                    }       

                    arrayRec.push(recJ);                            
                    console.log('-------arrayRec------');
                    console.log(arrayRec)
                    aps.walk.setupBootstrap(arrayRec);      
                }                       
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('get failure');
            }               
        });
    }
```

Tried many ways but what I am missing?

Comment: Tried with `onShow: newFunction1`?

Comment: newFunction1 : is showing function onshowdata(counter){                    
                        if(responseData[counter].fields.on_show_fn != null){
                            return function responseData[counter].fields.on_show_fn;
                        }               
                        else
                        return;
                    }                                                                              But not returning action or value

Comment: How are you calling it? recJ.onShow(something)?

Comment: onShow: function () {
     $('#proposal_detail_div #proposal_header_div #proposal_header_details_div').accordion('option', 'active', 0)
    }

Comment: Apparently you and I are not talking about the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

in JSON, only text can be used, not objects. Functions are objects too. So, in JSON, name of the function can be passed, not the function object. An alternate way is to send the text of that entire function, which can be run using "eval", though this way is not recommended.

Use closure technique here. Define function above the ajax code, and use the name of the function inside it, which is a standard method of doing this.